# Why can't I install Windows defender on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, antivirus

I would like windows defender as my anti-virus on Ubuntu why can't I install it?

Comment: Just because Ubuntu is not Windows.

Comment: Also, Windows Defender is not an anti-virus.  It's just a firewall.  It isn't protecting you from viruses at all.  On Ubuntu, if you want a firewall, you can use `ufw`/`gufw`.  For anti-virus, there is `clamav`.

Comment: @Ray In the past five years since Defender's introduction, in Windows it DOES provide very basic antivirus and antimalware for free.  It is, however, not an alternative for *fully fledged* antivirus solutions.   Defender's "firewall" also, by the way, isn't actually a Defender component but a Windows component - the Windows firewall, just rebranded as 'Defender Firewall' for business management/integration with InTune, MS365, etc. for management and deployment of rules.

Comment: Why would you at all expect to be able to install Windows system tools, highly integrated with the Windows OS, on a completely different OS?

Answer (score 4):

Windows Defender has numerous components, bare minimum basic antivirus, basic antimalware, etc.  Unfortunately, **all of the Windows Defender components are fully integrated into Microsoft Windows**, meaning you cannot get them on Ubuntu.

Ubuntu is not Windows, and thus Windows integrated components like Defender are not available in any way on Ubuntu.